# combining FILTER formula in Google Sheets

Tags: arrays, google-sheets, filter, google-sheets-formula, google-sheets-query

https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1St7OTtb69rj00qsq_C7vhtSD1VEUVUL9ekAmguBcc-M/edit?usp=sharing

the case above shows:

1. there are two tables of data (city and country)
2. I can filter each of the data according to a certain category
3. I can combine both filter result manually by putting one above another

THE QUESTION:
is there any formula that can combine both filters (city and country) so that we got the expected result as shown in cell J2:J9??

Answer (score 11, accepted):

use:

```
={FILTER(A:A, B:B="yes"); 
  FILTER(D:D, E:E="yes")}
```

[image: 0]

---

or:

```
=FILTER({A:A; D:D}, {B:B; E:E}="yes")
```

[image: 0]

---

or:

```
=QUERY({A:B; D:E}, "select Col1 where Col2 = 'yes'")
```

[image: 0]

Comment: I am encountering super weird issues. I tested your solution with a small sample and it works fine, but when I am applying it to my big dataset, it only displays the first half (in this example the cities). Setting the data range only for the second half (Countries), it also works fine but not for both. Any idea?

Comment: @VincenzoKöstler can you share a copy of your sheet?

Comment: definitely!! Thank you:)

https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1wrTSLKLPdENPCKyfnovp4-Yr-dLKtPLVQn23LLJ2Y2k/edit?usp=sharing

That is the file. Data is stored in "import" and the merging I am talking about is done in Sheet "Selection (Round 2)".

Comment: works like a charm. how do you know this shit?

Comment: @masbro https://developers.google.com/chart/interactive/docs/querylanguage

Comment: @player0 not the QUERY , but the FILTER function with ;

Comment: @masbro see: https://stackoverflow.com/q/73767719/5632629